# Reindex task/mapper/job for AppEngine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, mapreduce, objectify

Does anybody know of a library or good code sample that could be used to re-index all/some entities in all/some namespaces ?

If I implement this on my own, is MapReduce what I should consider ?

"I need to re-index ?" feels like a problem many developers have run into but the closest I could find is [this](https://code.google.com/p/walkaround/source/browse/src/com/google/walkaround/wave/server/index/ReIndexMapper.java), which may be a good start ?

Other option is a homebrewn solution using Task Queues that iterate the datastore namespaces and entities but I'd prefer not the re-invent the wheel and go for a robust, proven solution.

What are the options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't know of any pre-built system. I think you basically need to create a cursor to iterate through all your entities and then do a get and a put on all of them (or optionally check if they're in the index before doing the put - if you have some that won't need updating, that would save you a write at the cost of a read and/or a small operation).

Follow the example here:
https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Cursors

1. Create a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue to hold batches of datastore keys.
2. Create 10 new consumer threads (the current limit) using ThreadManager:
   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager
   Those threads should do the following:

   1. Create a new objectify instance and turn off the session cache and memcache for objectify.
   2. Get a batch of keys from the SynchronousQueue.
   3. Fetch all of those entities using a batch get.
   4. *Optionally do a keys-only query for all those entities using the relevant property.*
   5. Put all those entities *(or exclude the ones that were returned above)*.
   6. Repeat from step 2.
3. In a loop, fetch the next 30 keys using a keys-only cursor query and put them into the SynchronousQueue.
4. Once you've put all of the items into the SynchronousQueue, set a property to stop all the consumer threads once they've done their work.

Comment: I will need some time to try this out. So you suggest a custom implementation without using MapReduce. Is this not exactly the scope of MapReduce and doesn't MapReduce do this looping already ?

Comment: There are issues with either method. With the one I've suggested, you have to manage the work yourself which is a problem that grows with the size of the task. I'd guess that if you're indexing in the order of a million entities as a one-off, my solution is probably easier than dealing with Python/Java/Objectify indexing issues. The decision of what to index is trivial to convey in Objectify but harder to translate to Python I think.